# Map[] myArr, each with <K>Integer, <V>HashSet ... can't get to HashSet (Java)

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, hashset

I'm not able to navigate down to the HashSets in my datastructure

I declared an array of Map[] and populated it with HashMap with K of Integer, and V of HashSet of String but was unable to add items to the HashSet.

I've trimmed the code down to illustrate ...

```
private Map[] myMaps = null;

myMaps = new Map[numRepeats];
myMaps[0] = new HashMap<Integer,HashSet<String>>();
myMaps[0].put(0, new HashSet<String>());
```

The popup in NetBeans shows I can get to java.util.Map with

```
myMaps[0].
```

but using the map.get(0) method I thought would return the HashSet

```
myMaps[0].get(0).
```

shows I've got to generic java.lang.object, not to the HashSet. Since I need to use the HashSet.add() method next this means I'm stuck. I would appreciate suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: You have an array of maps of sets? You need some classes in there, or you're going to be tearing your hair out while debugging!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define your map, you could define it with the full types involved, so:

```
private Map<Integer, HashSet<String>>[] myMaps = null;
```

Then, you wouldn't have to cast it back (assuming all your maps in myMaps will be of that type).

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast it to `HashMap<Integer,HashSet<String>>`.

Comment: Thanks, there's a consensus with Dante617 that this is the way fwd

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Java Generics make it rather tricky to have an array of a generic class.  However, it is possible, and it will solve your problem in a typesafe way.

1st.  declare your map like this

```
private Map<Integer,Set<String>>[] myMaps = null;
```

2nd.  use a utility function to allocate

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] newMapArray( int size )
{
    return (T[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Map.class, size);
}
```

3rd.  allocate myMaps like this

```
myMaps = newMapArray(numRepeats);
```

Comment: Thanks. umm, it's early days in Java for me and that looks a plateful. I'll study it and read around the suggestion. In the meantime I'm using Map<Integer, HashSet<String>>[] myMaps = null; (because I understand it).thanks

Comment: @bobox I certainly can understand why that looks intimidating.  The nice thing about it is you can put it in some utility class and reuse it anywhere you like.  Also, it hides the unchecked casts.